# D3 change visibilty of nodes on click based on class

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bubble chart, where nodes are declared as below and I append for each circle a class which is decided by a array ("category") which decides its category, the variable color is d3.scale.category10() .domain(d3.range(number of elements in "category" array));.

```
 var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) {return category[d.cluster];})
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
        .filter(function(d){ return d.count >= 1; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.cluster); })
        .call(force.drag);
```

Next, I make a legend which depends on the categories of each of the circles with their color (as shown above). For this, I do the following

```
 var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width - 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", color)

 legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) { return category[d]; })
```

Now, what I want is that when the user clicks the legend text, then  the bubbles corresponding to the category of the legend be hidden.

So I add the following to the legend, text object.

```
.on("click", function(d){
            node.selectAll('.'+category[d]).style("visibility", "hidden");
            });
```

But, this does not hide the nodes. Please help.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `node.selectAll()` it will select all childs of this node that fit the selector. In your case you want to call it on document. So you have to do something like `d3.selectAll('.'+category[d])`